# How to avoid recreation/redrwraing of fragment's contents when using ActionBarSherlock TabPageIndicator

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am using TabPageIndicator to create a tab layout. Everything is working great except for the fact that if I go from tab 1 to tab 2 and if I come back to tab1, my tab1's contents(2 images loaded from an url) stay there and do not get refreshed. However, when I move 1 tab over or more, say from 1 to 2 and then to 3, then 1 apparently gets deleted, and when I come back to 1, my images have to load again. I am trying to avoid redrwaing the images again by keeping the fragment alive as I will at most have about 6 tabs and their data will be persistent for the most part.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int) to make viewpager load and keep all offscreen tab. Set to 2 ( tabCount - 1) like: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

Comment: Please post this as an answer! It is exactly what I was looking for !!!

Comment: okay, I've posted it in the answer. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int) to make viewpager load and keep all offscreen tab. Set to 2 ( tabCount - 1) like: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

Hope this help.